# How can I create a version of the Facebook iOS homescreen in HTML and CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios

I know that Facebook uses the Three20 library to get the icons on its homescreen, but how can this be similarly achieved in just plain HTML and CSS?

I would imagine that I would need to use some kind of positioning such as tables for the icons.

Is there a tutorial out there which could help?

Answer (score 0):

If you add some jquery in there you get some of the functionality too :
http://tutorialzine.com/2011/10/ios-homescreen-coffeescript/

OR

http://chrismcclellan.com/2011/04/ios-homescreen-replica/

Comment: By the way, the first one, if you drag it sideways it drags just like the IOS homescreen too